# Sharepoint 2010, any way to get a hash of a row?

Tags: 2010

I have a scenario where I have a list with 1 unique field and about 25 other fields making up the rest of the list.

When I do an update on the list item. I would like to only update the item if something has changed. Is there a way to get a hash for the list item so I can test the hash, rather than having to update each and every time.

I guess I could do this using string concatenation of the field values, but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Why not check the Last Modified Date?

If that's not sufficient you have to make your own hash of the object, perhaps using the SPListItem.Xml property.